# Sequelize Автоматическое создание нескольких строк в одной базе ассоциированных с другой

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Проблема: Допустим у нас есть пользователь данные которого записаны в одной базе. к нему идет в добавок другая база под название Балансы. в этой базе записаны разные валюты и объем средств в этой валюте которые доступны этому пользователю

```
User [{id: 1, name: 'Mickl'}, {id: 2, name: 'Seth'}]

Balance [
 {id:1, currency: 'USD', value: 10, id_user: 1}, 
 {id:2, currency: 'EUR', value: 30, id_user: 1}
 {id:3, currency: 'USD', value: 50, id_user: 2}
]
```

как сделать так чтобы при записывании в первую базу User автоматически создавались данные в балансе с 2 двумя валютами и ествественно с нулевым балансом
то есть заходит новый пользователь сразу создается в базе {id: 3, name: 'Jake'} и потом сразу же к нему в балансе прописываются данные c usd и eur value: 0. можно ли это правило создания автоматом прописать в схеме баланса в Sequelize

p.s. я понимаю что можно просто в ручную прописать создание этих строк, но вот как это масштабировать потом хз, если допустим нужно сразу присвоить 100 валют.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать так

```
    await userModel.create([{
        name: user.name,
        balances: user.balances
        ...
    }], {
        include: [{
            model: balanceModel,
        }]
    })
```

Обрати внимание, что переменная balances во множественном числе